# Add shape to top right corner of power point slide using C# and Power point addin

Tags: c#, powerpoint, shapes, office-addins

I currently adding a shape to the top left corner of my slide in my powerpoint addin using c# using this method [AddShape()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744336(v=office.15).aspx) But as you can see this takes top left as the parameters. I was wondering if there was a way of assing the shape to the top right corner instead? Maybe measure the page and feed the left parameter in as an absolute value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up doing what I said in the question. Using [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/31e04ad2-1820-4c9f-9cd3-75f9463b840b/how-do-i-find-the-pixel-dimensions-of-a-powerpoint-slide-with-vstovs2008?forum=vsto)

I did:

```
PowerPoint.Application ppApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
left = ppApp.ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth - //my image size - //my margin;
```

then feed that parameter into the AddShape() method linked in the question